# R levelplot adjust axes

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

I want to plot the probability distribution function (PDF) as a heatmap in R using the levelplot function of the "lattice" package. I implemented PDF as a function and then generated the matrix for the levelplot using two vectors for the value ranges and the outer function.
I want the axes to display the  My issue is that am not able to add properly spaced tickmarks on the two axes displaying the two actual value ranges instead of the number of columns or rows, respectively.

```
# PDF to plot heatmap
P_RCAconst <- function(x,tt,D)
  {
    1/sqrt(2*pi*D*tt)*1/x*exp(-(log(x) - 0.5*D*tt)^2/(2*D*tt))
  }

# value ranges & computation of matrix to plot
tt_log <- seq(-3,3,0.05)
tt <- exp(tt_log)
tt <- c(0,tt)
x <- seq(0,8,0.05)
z <- outer(x,tt,P_RCAconst, D=1.0)
z[,1] <- 0
z[which(x == 1),1] <- 1.5
z[1,] <- 0.1

# plot heatmap using levelplot
require("lattice")
colnames(z) <- round(tt, 2)
rownames(z) <- x
levelplot(z, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5, col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow","red", "black")), at=seq(0,1.9,length=200), xlab="x", ylab="time t", main="PDF P(x,t)")
```

Without assigning names to columns and rows I receive the following plot where the tick marks are naturally spaced (as used from other R-functions) but the values are the row & column numbers:
[image: Without assigning names to columns and rows I receive the following plot where the tick marks are naturally spaced (as used from other R-functions) but the values are the row & column numbers]

With assigning names to columns and rows I receive the following plot where the tick marks are not at all readable but at least correspond to the actual values:

[image: With assigning names to columns and rows I receive the following plot where the tick marks are not at all readable but at least correspond to the actual values]

I have spent already too much time on this seemingly trivial issue so I would appreciate very much any help from your side!

Comment: the doc of lattice is very complete, have you read it twice? `?levelplot` `?xyplot`

Comment: Yes. For instance, it suggests `scale` as possible argument to modify the axes, i.e. with tick.number. But when I tried this, it neither had any effect nor threw it an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this basic example can help,

```
d = data.frame(x=rep(seq(0, 10, length=nrow(volcano)), ncol(volcano)), 
               y=rep(seq(0, 100, length=ncol(volcano)), each=nrow(volcano)), 
               z=c(volcano))

library(lattice)

# let lattice pick pretty tick positions
levelplot(z~x*y, data=d)

# specific tick positions and labels
levelplot(z~x*y, data=d, scales=list(x=list(at=c(2, 5, 7, 9), 
                                            labels=letters[1:4])))

# log scale
levelplot(z~x*y, data=d, scales=list(y=list(log=TRUE)))
```

It's all described in `?xyplot`, though admittedly it is a long page of documentation.

Comment: My problem is actually simple: I want the x-axis to display values from 0 to 8 and the y-axis to display values from 0 to 20 (or `exp(3)`). The first picture features the right value but in a obviously useless way (since it overlaps all of them). The second picture has nice axes but which display completely wrong values, i.e. the row and col numbers.

Comment: your question seems to be missing some code, I see only one call to levelplot, and no example of your use of scales.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I actually noticed this volcano example from a different post and indeed there it seems to work. I have to admit that I did not try to adapt it to my problem since I don't have any experience with data frames in R. However, since you pointed out this example again I tried my best and finally worked out! I simply wrote: `d = data.frame(x=rep(seq(0, 8, length=nrow(zz)), ncol(zz)), 
               y=rep(seq(0, 20, length=ncol(zz)), each=nrow(zz)), 
               z=c(zz))`, where `zz` is the previous variable `z`, and then the levelplot function as mentioned in your post.

Comment: Now refering to your second comment: I think I now see your point. My code above is actually complete, I have now separate line for the use of scales. I first tried to set the scales within the levelplot function itself using some arguments, but I also tried it with something like panel.axis(side="bottom", draw.labels=TRUE, check.overlap=TRUE, outside=TRUE, ticks=TRUE)and lattice.options(skip.boundary.labels=0)` but without success.

Comment: For my future plots with lattice: May I ask you how you would have handled the scales in my example? And how would you implement a logarithmic scale? Thank you!

Comment: I still don't understand your initial post above: the two figures seem swapped, if I refer to the text, and there's no code that would correspond to the first plot you show (with the many labels overlapping).

Comment: You're right, the two plots were of course swapped. Sorry for the confusion. The code above is complete. With the lines `colnames(z) <- round(tt, 2)` and `rownames(z) <- x` you get the plot with overlapping labels, without these two lines you get the plot with the nice but wrong numbered labels. I executed the above code in order to check and I was able to reproduce the two figures. Is there anything you want me to add in order to clarify my problem? Do you know how to implement logarithmic axes? Thank you.

Comment: I see; I'd never have thought of using row/colnames for this purpose, so I mentally skipped those lines.

Answer (score 2):

This how I finally implemented the heatmap plot of my function P(x,t) using `levelplot`and a `data.frame`object (according to the solution provided by baptiste):

```
# PDF to plot heatmap
P_RCAconst <- function(xx,tt,D)
  {
    1/sqrt(2*pi*D*tt)*1/xx*exp(-(log(xx) - 0.5*D*tt)^2/(2*D*tt))
  }

# value ranges & computation of matrix to plot
tt_end <- 20                              # set end time
xx_end <- 8                              # set spatial boundary
tt <- seq(0,tt_end,0.01)                 # variable for time
xx <- seq(0,xx_end,0.01)                 # spatial variable
zz <- outer(xx,tt,P_RCAconst, D=1.0)     # meshgrid for P(x,t)
zz[,1] <- 0                              # set initial condition
zz[which(xx == 1),1] <- 4.0              # set another initial condition
zz[1,] <- 0.1                            # set boundary condition

# plot heatmap using levelplot
setwd("/Users/...")                      # set working dirctory
png(filename="heatmapfile.png", width=500, height=500) #or: x11()
par(oma=c(0,1.0,0,0))                    # set outer margins
require("lattice")                       # load package "lattice"
d = data.frame(x=rep(seq(0, xx_end, length=nrow(zz)), ncol(zz)),
               y=rep(seq(0, tt_end, length=ncol(zz)), each=nrow(zz)), 
               z=c(zz))
levelplot(z~x*y, data=d, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5, cex.main=1.5, col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow","red", "black")), at=c(seq(0,0.5,0.01),seq(0.55,1.4,0.05),seq(1.5,4.0,0.1)), xlab="x", ylab="time t", main="PDF P(x,t) for RC A, constant population")
dev.off()
```

And that is how the final heatmap plot of my function P(x,t) looks like:

[image: Final heatmap of the function P(x,t)]